# router.navigate doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have tried to redirect the page after getting data successfully deleted. So I put the redirect router.navigate inside of the subscribe of the data section. But it's not working and also I have tried with ngZone also nothing happens. And I want to show the success message also. How can I show that?

without ngZone:

```
  const rid = params['rid'];
        this.roleSer.deleteRole(rid).subscribe(

            data => { this.router.navigate(['viewroles']) },
            error => { error }
        );
    });
```

with ngZone:

```
const vrid = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const rid = params['rid'];
        this.roleSer.deleteRole(rid).subscribe(
            data => { this.zone.run(()=>{
                 this.router.navigate(['viewroles']) 
            }); },
            error => { error }
        );
    });
```

Comment: what is this.zone.run(()?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried. But not working

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: make sure your path is right?

Answer (score 1):

Create one redirect function and use it

```
const vrid = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            const rid = params['rid'];
            this.roleSer.deleteRole(rid).subscribe(
                data => { 
                    this.redirect('viewroles');
                },
                error => { error }
            );
        });

    redirect(path): void {
     this.router.navigate(['/' + path]) 
    }
```